# Create2 Serial. Canonical versus Number of Bytes interface

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

There is a message system which does not appear to be document in the OI spec. This appears to be a a canonical terminal type serial interface in which messages come back such as firmware version and stuff. I am not sure how to determine what the end of this type of message is? It is a fixed number of end lines? or Bytes. One message seems to indicate STR730 which would be a 730 byte string.

The open interface spec seems to indicate a non canonical interface spec in which you read a fixed number of bytes with no processing of end lines. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to worry about those messages (or length of) since they are disabled once the OI is started (with the start command '128'). After OI is started, flush whatever data is on the line then request your desired sensor data.

As you noted, these are mainly just firmware/hardware version strings. There is no defined length of these messages, but they should always be terminated by "\r\n".

Comment: The problem is you have to clear that terminal type canonical message buffer out before you can get to sensor data you requested in the non canonical number of byte interface.

Comment: You can flush the serial data 1 second after starting the OI. From that point forward, you can then request/stream sensor data and not have to worry about the other messages at all.